# Check if string ends with the beginning of another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following two strings: `"Hey there"` and `"there is a ball"`

I want the output to be `True`, because the first one ends with `"there"` and the second one begins with `"there"`.

Also, it would be helpful if I could know the length of the overlap.

Comment: Have you tried doing anything?

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions or Regex.

Comment: What about `Hey there` and `therefore it is true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def endOverlap(a, b):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if b.startswith(a[-i:]):
            return i
    return 0

a = "Hey there"
b = "there is a ball"
c = "here is a ball"
d = "not here is a ball"

print(a, b, endOverlap(a, b))
print(a, c, endOverlap(a, c))
print(a, d, endOverlap(a, d))
```

*Edit: modified to return length of overlap and to be more efficient if only small parts of the string are expected to overlap. Then fixed a bug.*

Comment: You could return the length of the overlap, rather than `True`/`False`, as an overlap of `0` (i.e. no overlap) would evaluate false-y in a boolean context.

Comment: OP specifically asked for boolean `True`, but of course you can modify it by returning `len(a)-i`.

Comment: Indeed, that was based on *"Also, it would be helpful if I could know the length of the overlap."*

Comment: Yes, my mistake - `[-0:]` is actually the whole string, not `''`; I briefly thought it would *always* return `0`!

Comment: The `endOverlap` function will require exponential time because `b.startswith` requires runtime linear to the length of the given argument. Note how `b.startswith` is called repeatedly with every increasing string lengths; this is [Shlemiel's algorithm](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_Algorithm).

Comment: Yes, I suspect that there is a more efficient version, but I am not sure whether that would be overkill in OPs case.

Comment: @jojonas The solution I propose uses less code and needs linear time.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You didn't propose a working solution.

Comment: @jojonas Oops, indeed! I deleted my answer now, thanks for double-checking that!

Comment: Now I actually wonder if there is a solution better than `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# do your str checks here...
if (str1.split()[-1] == str2.split()[0]):
```

Comment: This only works if the overlap is a whole word, which may not be the case

Comment: @jonrsharpe always appreciate your input, thanks. I notice it becomes much complicated when you consider character overlap

Answer (score 0):

To know overlap of two strings use generator and `endswith` string method. The `max` value of this substring will be the max overlap:

```
>>> str1 = "Hey there"
>>> str2 = "there is a ball"
>>> overlap = max((str2[:x] for x in range(1,len(str2) + 1) if str1.endswith(str2[:x])),key = len)
>>> overlap
'there'
```

To return `True` use `if` statements or `bool` type:

```
>>> if overlap:
...     print True
... 
True
>>> bool(overlap)
True
```

To know the length just use `len` function:

```
>>> len(overlap)
5
```

Comment: You should use `max((x for x in range....))`, this solution only works because `max(('foo', 'foob, 'foobar'))` is the longest word (they're compared alphabetically).

Comment: `max` is used for repeating overlaps:                                                                                                           `>>> str3 = '111'`                                                                                     `>>> str4 = '11111'`                                                                                   `>>> [str4[:x] for x in range(1,len(str4) + 1) if str3.endswith(str4[:x])]`   `['1', '11', '111']`

Comment: Yes, and `max` will choose the alphabetically ordered last string. See (independent of your example) this example: `max(('aaaaaaa', 'b', 'c'))` will return `c` and *not* the longest string, which ould be `aaaaaaa`.

Comment: Oops... Yes, max for strings returns alpha first meaning. Thanks, I should rewrite my solution.