# How to determine if one string starts with what another ends with

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a list of phrases:

```
[
  "according to all known laws of aviation",
  "time flies when you're having fun..."
  ...
]
```

I would like to find all the phrases in this list that match with the end of an input string. For example:

```
getNext("did you know that time flies w")
```

should perform a search through the list to match any string that starts with what `did you know that time flies w` ends with. As an example, it should return a list that at least contains `time flies when you're having fun` since itends with `time flies w` which is the start of that phrase.

I can't think of any reasonable way to do this.

The only thing I can think of is running through each character in the input and check if it matches the start of the phrase. If it does, increment a counter. If it is >1 (or some other number) at the end of the loop, at the phrase to another list, along with the number of matches. From there I could sort the list to give the closest match first, and the less close ones last.

Surely there must be a better way to do this?

For a bit of background, you can see [this Repl.it project](https://repl.it/@davwheat/AutocompleteText) and [this very similar Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458737/check-if-string-ends-with-the-beginning-of-another-string).

Comment: But `time flies when you're having fun` does not **end** with `time flies w`

Comment: How do you determine what a phrase "ends with"? Because in the example you list, it's one string that starts with exactly another string. What happens if you input `one two time` - should you still return `time flies when you're having fun`?

Comment: @Pointy well it **starts** with `time flies w`. And the string  `time flies w` technically **ends** with the entire phrase. So I'm a bit confused

Comment: _"I haven't thought of any reasonable way to do this"_ - Then this question should not have been asked in the first place. We are not here to show you all the ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: To me "having fun" would be what "time flies when you're having fun" ends with.

Comment: @Pointy I guess you got it wrong *"check if any of the lines start with what the textbox in the HTML page ends in"* We are looking for endOf(textbox) === startOf(textfile.line[i]) `time flies when you're having fun` is in textfile, `time flies w` is input (in textbox)

Comment: @VLAZ I fixed the example, sorry about that.

Comment: @Kaiido what does "end of" mean? What definition of `endOf()` would return `true` for "time flies w" against the longer string?

Comment: @Pointy I have no clue about this, let OP clarify, but your comment is off anyhow. VLAZ's comment exactly asks about this though.

Comment: OK well I clicked through to the other linked question and that's got a perfectly clear answer as to how the comparison should work.

Comment: @Pointy I mean that if the textbox has `did you know that time flies w` should return `time flies when you're having fun` because the textbox ends in `time flies w` and one of the lines in the text file starts with `time flies w`

Comment: Your question does NOT appear to meet any minimal complete example standards here.  Please revise such that it does, including what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I haven't thought of any way to do this, which is WHY it doesn't include what I have tried.

Comment: @DavidWheatley the Python question has an excepted answer that does exactly what you want though

Comment: @DavidWheatley I took the liberty of rewritting your question entirely, in the hope of making it more clear. If you disagree with this edit, feel free to rollback the edit (by clicking on the timestamp [edited nnn ago]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite frustrated that I answer here, without anything better than the brute-force... I would really have enjoyed a more clever way to go through it, and still hope someone will.

But given your application, there a a few optimizations you must add on jojonas' algorithm. You are probably going to perform this check at each keystroke, and since it is an autocomplete, the input may grow in length pretty fast.

One first optimization is to cut the input to the length of the checked string.
Given an input of length 8, and a string to compare of length 3, there is no way the first 5 iterations return a match

```
input:   "aaaaaaaa" (8)
compare:      "aaa" (3)
               ^- first possible match for compare.startsWith()
```

This can be quite easily done by initiating our iterator to `max(input.length - compare.length, 0)`.

A second optimization to this algorithm consist in searching for the first index of the first letter of `compare` inside the remainder of `input`. No need to go through every characters, as long as it isn't the first one of `compare` we can be sure that `compare.startsWith` will return false. We can then repeat until we find which remainder is correct, once again removing quite a few loops in the whole process.

```js
const phrases = ["according to all known laws of aviation", "a blessing in disguise", "a bunch", "a dime a dozen", "beat around the bush", "better late than never", "bite the bullet", "break a leg", "call it a day", "cut somebody some slack", "cutting corners", "dead tired", "easy does it", "excuse me", "get it out of my system", "get it out of your system", "get out of hand", "get something out of my system", "get something out of your system", "get your act together"];


inp.oninput = e => {
  const overlaps = getOverlaps(inp.value, phrases);
  makeList(overlaps);
  if(logged) console.clear();
};
let logged = false;
inp.oninput(); 
logged = true;

// "abcde", "def"
function getOverlaps(input, list) {
  return list.filter(compare => {
    // single logger, just for demo
    const log = (...args) => !logged && compare === "beat around the bush" && console.log.apply(console, args);

    // search only in possible area
    let i = Math.max(input.length - compare.length, 0); // 2
    
    log('initial i:', i);
    
    const first_letter = compare[0]; // "d"
    let remain = input.substr(i); // "cde"
    
    log('initial remain:', remain);
    
    while(i < input.length) {
      // jump to first letter
      let index = remain.indexOf(first_letter); // 1

      log('in-loop index:', index);

      if(index < 0) { // not found
        return false;
      }
      i += index; // 3
      remain = input.substr(i); // "de"
      
      log('in-loop remain:', remain);
      
      if(compare.startsWith(remain)) { // found
        return true; // =>
      }
      
      // wasn't this one, move by one char
      // (will jump to next occurence of first_letter) at next iteration
      i++;
      remain = input.substr(i);
    }
      
  });

}

function makeList(items) {
  list.innerHTML = '';
  items.forEach(e => 
    list.appendChild(
      document.createElement('li')
    ).textContent = e
  );
}
```

```css
body{padding-bottom: 120px}
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="according to all known laws of aviation to bring a beat a" autofocus>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you JUST want to match the start of some array of strings, you can use a `filter` and a `startsWith` function pair.

```
  let test = "a ";
  const items = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.startsWith(test));
```

NOTE IF you do not care and as your strings are all lower case use `.toLowerCase()` to make it match "I" and "i";

```
  let test = "a ";
  const items = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.toLowerCase().startsWith(test));
```

Note: I edited this live example to show "contains" as well via a checkbox, just in case that helps illustrate an alternative.

Here is a live example:

```js
let phrases = ["according to all known laws of aviation", "a blessing in disguise", "a bunch", "a dime a dozen", "beat around the bush", "better late than never", "bite the bullet", "break a leg", "call it a day", "cut somebody some slack", "cutting corners", "dead tired", "easy does it", "excuse me", "get it out of my system", "get it out of your system", "get out of hand", "get something out of my system", "get something out of your system", "get your act together", "give someone the benefit of the doubt", "go back to the drawing board", "good idea", "hang in there", "hit the nail on the head", "hit the sack", "how does that sound?", "i don't know", "i don't understand", "i love you", "i owe you one", "i'm fine", "i'm fine, thanks", "i'm really sorry", "i'm sorry", "it cost an arm and a leg", "it costs an arm and a leg", "it'll cost an arm and a leg", "it will cost an arm and a leg", "it's not rocket science", "i've never given it much thought", "kill two birds with one stone", "killing two birds with one stone", "let you off the hook", "let me off the hook", "look, it's", "make a long story short", "miss the boat", "never gonna give you up", "no pain,  no gain ", "on the ball ", "once upon a time ", "pull your leg ", "pulling your leg ", "pull yourself together ", "proof of concept ", "so far so good ", "so much ", "speak of the devil ", "thanks so much ", "thank you so much ", "that's the last straw ", "the best of both worlds ", "this is a test", "time flies when you're having fun", "to be honest", "to get bent out of shape", "to kill a mockingbird", "to make matters worse", "under the weather", "watch out", "we'll cross that bridge when we come to it ", "whatever floats your boat", "whatever you say ", "wrap your head around something", "you can say that again", "your guess is as good as mine", "there's no such thing as a free lunch", "throw caution to the wind", "you can't have your cake and eat it too ", "have your cake and eat it too", "judge a book by its cover ", "book by its cover", "last straw", "shut up", "be quiet", "how are you?", "never gonna give you up", "water under the bridge", "let you down", "birds and the bees", "pair of trainers", "i'd really like", "i wouldn't mind", "i could do with"];

$('#mywords').on('input change', function(event) {
  let grp = $("<div></div>");
  let test = $(this).val();
  $('#testing').html(test);
  const items = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.startsWith(test));
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    let rowItem = $("<div class='row-item'></div>").text(index + ". " + value);
    grp.append(rowItem);
  });
  $('#results-list').html(grp.children());
});

function dochange(event) {
  let grp = $("<div></div>");
  let test = $('#mywords').val();
  $('#testing').html(test);
  let items = [];
  if (!$('#mywords-contain').prop('checked')) {
    items = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.toLowerCase().startsWith(test));
  } else {
    items = phrases.filter(phrase => phrase.toLowerCase().includes(test));
  }
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    let rowItem = $("<div class='row-item'></div>").text(index + ". " + value);
    grp.append(rowItem);
  });
  $('#results-list').html(grp.children());
}

$('#mywords-contain').on('change', dochange);
$('#mywords').on('input change', dochange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Enter something:<input id="mywords" type="text"/></label><label>Check For contains:<input id="mywords-contain" type="checkbox"/></label><span id="testing">(empty)</span>
<div id="result-group">Result found:
  <div id="results-list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will leave it to you if you also wish to include or use the JavaScript `endsWith()` function.

Comment: The problem is way more complex. They want to find the phrases starting with the end of input. E.g `"foo beat a"` should find `beat around...` and all the phrases that start with `a`, like `"according to.."`.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the answer from the Python question into Javascript after doing some research  on the Python language:

```
function OverlapTest(input, compare) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (compare.startsWith(input.substring(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will return `true` if the strings overlap at the start and end and `false` if they don't.

Comment: @Kaiido That's what I was coming to... Exactly why I said I couldn't think of any *reasonable* way to do this. I was hoping someone would have a better and faster way to do this, but instead I got people complaining at me.

Comment: @DavidWheatley - I at least am not "complaining" but suggesting that you improve the question - obviously we want to help if we can but actually taking PART of the linked code and the text as was done in the edit will and does help - including adding this code and "how can I make this better" perhaps.